# How do you get group name of the executing role in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a use case where I need to create a directory in all hosts in a group whose name will be the name of the group.

Eg :
I create a dynamic inventory file with output of the form :

```
{
   "db": ["host1", "host2", "host3"],
   "logs": ["host2"],
   "misc": ["host4"]
}
```

I need to create a directory by the name db in every host of the group db and directory named log in every host of the group log.

My playbook so far looks like :

```
- hosts: db
  tasks:
  - name: create db directory
    file: path=db state=directory

- hosts: logs
  tasks:
  - name: create logs directory
    file: path=logs state=directory
```

The number of groups is at least 10+. This may grow in the future. 
I want to write something that will be easily extendable and manageable for the future groups.

I read that ansible doesn't provide a default fact or variable for group name for the task. I see that this can be best done if I provide a variable like groupname in host.

Is there a better solution that could use looping instead of repeating the same task?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the magic variable `group_names`. The variable is a list (array) of all the groups the current host is in. More information is available per the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html)

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
  - name: create db directory
    file: 
      path: "{{ item }}" 
      state: directory
    with_items: "{{ group_names }}"
```

Disclaimer: Did not test this code.

Comment: This will create a directory named `group_names` on every single host.

Comment: That is true. I needed to use : "{{group_names}}"